# Scrapy: How do I send the urls in start_urls to my callback?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following code

```
start_urls = ['http://mydomain.com/results.php?123123123123']
rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'results.php'], restrict_xpaths=('//a[text()="Next"]')), callback='parse_item', follow=True, ),)
```

It parses everything except the first page. How can I fix this? The URL I specified in the start_urls also has results that I need to parse. I need to send the URL specified in start_urls also to go into my parse_item callback.

Comment: Do you receive any error message?

Comment: No, there are no errors. The response from the URLs in the rules are the ones that go into the callback. I need to send my start url also there because it contains results.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question incase anybody else had the same problem. Just renaming my callback from `parse_item` to `parse_start_url` did the trick. Now the start URL(s) AND the URLs extracted by the rules are sent to my callback.

Comment: How to change defualt call back method for start_urls? which is `def parese(response)`